# Captions and subcaptions of a very long table

Tags: captions, longtable

I have a very long table that spans multiple pages. On top of the table, there is a caption like 'Table 1: A list'. Now, for the parts of the table that spans to the next pages, I want to put something like 'Table 1 (continued)' on each every page right above the table. How can I do that?

Thank you for any advice.
Regards,
Tung

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{7cm}|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\caption{A list\label{tab:list}} \\ 
\hline
Name       &    Company     &  Catalog Number   &   Comments    \\ \hline
a          &    b           &   123             &               \\ \hline
c          &    d           &   522             &     xyz       \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Welcome at TeX.SX! You may like to open the reference manual of the longtable package, there is an example. http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable Those suitable commands are `\endhead`, `\endfirsthead`, `\endfoot` and `\endlastfoot`, page 4.

Comment: Please post small, compilable examples rather than code fragments - it is much more helpful to be able to copy-paste-compile to see what the problem is!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\caption*`. I'd also recommend using `booktabs` and dispensing with the vertical rules.

The weird page layout is just because you didn't provide an example I could use to reproduce the problem so I had to make a 3 line tabular span 2 pages...

```
\documentclass[a5paper,landscape,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage[hscale=.9,vscale=.2]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{7cm}p{2cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}}
\caption{A list\label{tab:list}} \\
\toprule
Name       &    Company     &  Catalog Number   &   Comments    \\ \midrule\endfirsthead
\caption*{\tablename{} \ref{tab:list} (continued)}\\
\toprule
Name       &    Company     &  Catalog Number   &   Comments    \\ \midrule\endhead
\bottomrule\endfoot
a          &    b           &   123             &               \\
c          &    d           &   522             &     xyz       \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: squished tabular]